# UIScrollView with Autolayout has different size in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout, frame

its simple. in Xcode 6 I add an scrollView to to the view which covers entire screen. add constraints like this:

[image]

then add a contentView in the scrollView:

[image]

then add a sample label:

[image]

the problem is here when I run it on device with iOS 8: the scrollview width is **320** 
but on device with iOS 7 width is **320+16 = 336**

what am I doing wrong here? why scroll won't remain 320? this cause my custom collectionView flowLayout doesn't work well in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I guessed it was because of using margins which was introduced in iOS 8. but I was wondering I don't use margins when layouting view in the IB. after hours struggling, today I saw *I have used margins for the container of this View* controller.

removing margins fixed the problem.

so **if you want to support iOS 7 and below turn off constrain to margins when adding new constraints in the interface builder**